# PHP PDO Class do while

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, while-loop

Hello so I am using [this](http://pastebin.com/VLh2cFbv) PHP PDO Class and I am trying to code a do while loop. I never tested if it will work because I don't want to mess up my database. What I want to do is to generate a number, and if that number exists, I want it to generate another number. This is my code for now using the PDO Class:

```
$db = new db();
do {
        $generate_SID = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
        $bindCheck = array(
            ":sponsorID" => $generate_SID
        );
        $sponsorIDChecker = $db->select("accounts", "sponsorID = :sponsorID", $bindCheck);
    }while(count($sponsorIDChecker) > 0);
```

As you can see, the variable `$generate_SID` will generate a number, and the code below it will check if it exists in the database.

Will this work? Or should I place something outside the loop? Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend setting up a test db. You need to be able to test/modify code before running in production.

Comment: Executing SQL in a loop is almost always a bad idea. Are you sure it cannot be done without a loop?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Do you anything in mind that I can do without a loop?

Answer (score 0):

So I removed the SQL in the loop because as some people say, it's a bad idea. My code now looks like this:

```
$sponsorIDrandom = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
        $bindCheck = array(
            ":sponsorID" => $sponsorIDrandom
        );
    $sponsorIDChecker = $db->select("accounts", "sponsorID = :sponsorID", $bindCheck);

    do {
        $generate_SID = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
    }while(count($sponsorIDChecker) > 0);
```

I declared another variable for the `sponsorID` checking and then set another one inside the loop.